# Kingfisher 3.0 iOS swift RoundCornerImageProcessor white background

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

This is the code that I am using to set the user image which works great to actually get and set the image. I get a white outline to the picture. Any idea how to make this transparent?

```
let processor = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 50)
self.userPhoto.backgroundColor = Colors.accent
self.userPhoto.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "ic_camera_alt_48pt"), options: [.processor(processor)])
```

Example with 50
[image]

Comment: try         self.userPhoto.kf.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @KKRocks I don't see clipsToBounds on kingfisher only the image. I tried             self.userPhoto.clipsToBounds = true with no luck.

Comment: The image has to be a PNG with alpha channel in order to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 6):

The format of the original image doesn't support transparency (i.e. JPEG). You must convert the image to one that does (i.e. PNG) prior to caching.

From the [Kingfisher Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet):

> By default (DefaultCacheSerializer), Kingfisher will respect the input
>   image format and try to keep it unchanged. However, there are some
>   exceptions. A common case is that when you using a
>   RoundCornerImageProcessor, you may always want the alpha channel. If
>   your original image is jpg, you may want to set the png serializer
>   instead:

```
let roundCorner = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 20)
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, 
    options: [.processor(roundCorner), 
              .cacheSerializer(FormatIndicatedCacheSerializer.png)]
)
```

Comment: This is accepted answer, and just an addition, you may have to use clipToBounds=true on your UIImageView if you're using ResizingImageProcessor along with RoundCornerImageProcessor.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `RoundCornerImageProcessor`

```
self.userPhoto.layerCornerRadius = 50
self.userPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
self.userPhoto.backgroundColor = Colors.accent
self.userPhoto.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "ic_camera_alt_48pt"))
```